# Add check constraint to a table column in Apache derby database

Tags: sql, derby

I have a column with name 'status' in my table. The input for this column should be pending or complete or in progress.

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ADD CONSTRAINT status_ck CHECK (status IN('pending','complete','in progress'));
```

When I execute this code I get syntax error. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Do you really put `<table_name>` there, and not the actual table name?

Comment: Can you please include the *exact* syntax error? Cut-and-paste it from the output.

Comment: I put my actual table name in <table_name>

Comment: My Table structure is create table sample( id integer, status varchar(15) default 'Pending' not null); I executed the above code and it was successful but when i insert value its giving error. Insert Staement: insert into sample (id,status) values (1,'In Progress');

Comment: My error is: syntax error:encountered "user" at line 1 and column 15. here user is my schema name